# Dynamically display row of SQL table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I've been stuck on this for over a week now. I have an offline SQL database/website, the browser screen is split so that the full table is displayed on the bottom with limited details, you can click on the ID for a row and it should show a styled version of all the data contained in that row in the top half of the window. I know I need to use jquery and AJAX to accomplish this dynamically but I can't figure out how to grab the row data. This is only for a small personal project but I'm a complete amateur at this stuff and I'm really out of my depth now.

I've made a simpler version of my progress so far to demostrate where I'm stuck:

```css
/* main.css */

body {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

.outer_table {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    top: 50%;
 width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;

}

.inner_table {
    max-height: 50%;
    margin: 1rem;
}

#tabl1 {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    font-size: .8rem;
}

/* COLUMNS */

#column1{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left; 
    margin:0; 
    width:32%;
    height: 50%;
}
#column2{
    border: 1px solid red;
    float:left; 
    margin:0; 
    width:33%;
    height: 50%;
}
#column3{
    border: 1px solid green;
    float:left; 
    margin:0; 
    width:33%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mini");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM helptable");
?>



<body>

 <div id="column1">
 CONTENT 1
 id goes here
  <?php
    $profile = $_GET['id'];
    echo "<h2>" . $profile . "</h2>"
  ?>
 </div>
 <div id="column2">
 CONTENT 2
 <div id="#view1"></div>
 first name goes here
 </div>
 <div id="column3">
 CONTENT 3
 <div id="#view2"></div>
 surname goes here

 </div>

<div class="outer_table">
    <div class="inner_table">
  <table id="tabl1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
   </tfoot>

  <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">" . $row["id"] . "</a></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row["surname"] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysqli_close($con);
  ?>
 </div>
</div>



</body>
```

Here is an example .csv for the SQL table, anything like this really:

> id,firstname,surname
>   PP001,John,Lennon
>   PP002,Paul,McCartney
>   PP003,George,Harrison
>   PP004,Ringo,Starr

As you can see I've managed to figure out how to make the ID's into links which can be interpreted by the php code and displayed in column 1, but I can't figure out how to use that to get the rest of the information from the row and display it on the page dynamically. Clicking the ID 1 link and the firstName and lastName should display in column 2 and 3 respectively, same with all the other rows in the table.

I tried the method shown in the W3 tutorial using  modifying it slightly to use a php loop but that ended up a complete mess and isn't suitable.

Any help or assistance in finding where I can learn more would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: add ` ; ` to the end of `echo "<h2>" . $profile . "</h2>"`

Comment: @mamdouhfreelancer it actually still parses without the semi-colon; though, i would also add it for good measure/consistency.

Comment: Test the code given below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I can't solve it completely, but perhaps I can help.

1. You are right, your **a href** is pointing to a request that would include the id of the row you need.  Good.
2. Now, you need to change that from **href=\"?id=...** to **href=\"my_ajax.php?id=**
3. Don't click it yet! To truly do AJAX you'll need to add Javascript.  I see you don't have any here, so that may be the piece you're missing ( you might have a look at [this ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) )
4. Now that you are going to checkout AJAX later, just do it the cheap and simple way...don't do ajax at all...just build the page that shows what it is you want (my_ajax.php).  That may actually help you envision what you want (and it will let you "gracefully degrade" if AJAX isn't available).

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement :**

Display ID , first name , last name in a small table . When ever user clicks on id in table 1 detailed information should appear in another table on same page with help of AJAX.

**Theory :**

Ajax is a javascript which activates a php script DYNAMICALLY and display results on PAGE.As AJAX is ajava script it must be defined just like any other function. The function which defines AJAX and how AJAX will work is called as **AJAX framework **

- Ajax framework

ajax.js (add this to your pages by LINK or SRC)

```
function ajaxObj(meth, url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open(meth, url, true);
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

**How to use Ajax ? :**

HOW_TO_USE.php

```
<div id="column1">
    CONTENT 1
    id goes here
  <?php
    $profile = $_GET['id'];
    echo "<a onClick='show_details($id)'>" . $profile . "</a>"
  ?>
</div>
<div id='show'></div>
```

now define show_details() function

```
<script>
function show_details(x){
var id = x ;
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "admit_student.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                document.getElementById("Show").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("id="+id);
}
</script>
```

Now add php script :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM helptable");
$Ajax_echo_out = '<table>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
    $Ajax_echo_out = $Ajax_echo_out."<tr>"."<td><a href=\"?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">" . $row["id"] . "</a></td>"."<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td>"."<td>" . $row["surname"] . "</td>"."</tr>";
        }
    $Ajax_echo_out= $Ajax_echo_out."</table>";
echo $Ajax_echo_out;
exit();
}

?>
```

**How it works ?**

simply We call show_details , it activates POST id  to same page to activate php script , then php echo out result string , and finally AJAX.Response (which is echo statement from php function ) is printed out in SHOW div as HTML code

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `$_GET["id"]` was set or no then select from db to display.

test this example:

```
<html>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","mini");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["id"] !=""){
$profile = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);//or escape whatever
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM helptable WHERE id=$profile LIMIT 1");
}else{
die("ID Must be defined");
}

?>



<body>

    <div id="column1">
    CONTENT 1
    id goes here
  <?php

    echo "<h2>" . $profile . "</h2>";
  ?>
    </div>
    <div id="column2">
    CONTENT 2
    <div id="#view1"></div>
    first name goes here
    </div>
    <div id="column3">
    CONTENT 3
    <div id="#view2"></div>
    surname goes here

    </div>

<div class="outer_table">
    <div class="inner_table">
        <table id="tabl1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>

        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"?id=" . $row["id"] . "\">" . $row["id"] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["surname"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </div>
</div>



</body>
```

Comment: I tried this and get "ID Must be defined" when I load it in the browser, so I must be doing something wrong there.

Comment: so your `$_GET["id"]` was not set or was empty try input url to the browser `http://your_link/?id=1` or `http://your_link/path?id=1` with parameter `id=` and see result